Is this a fossil or something nonorganic?
I've found and object that has an unusual shape - claw like with cube shaped corner. Is it a fossil or only weird looking stone?





It might be coral, but then again it might also be something broken off a statue.

The location of the discovery could be helpful for identification.

I don't think this might be a part of the statue due to the location of find (rural area in northern lake district of Poland, post glacial area, so it could have been brought by glacier from anywhere north...)

Are those dimensions centimeters or inches?

@JohnHoltz Dimensions are in centimeters.

its so well weathered it is impossible to say from just pics, lick it, if your tongue sticks to it it is probably a fossil.

@John I've tried to touch it with my tongue and it sticks.

which means it is highly micro-pourous, which means biological, but it could be fossil or extant like corral.

It looks like it might be a flint nodule? Sometimes they are funny irregular shapes as I gather they can form by silica from e.g. sponges precipitating out into hollows and voids created by creatures that burrow in mud.  I have some that have fossils (e.g. corals or impressions of echinoids etc.) in them, but you could say that funny shaped ones are trace fossils recording the activity of burrowing sea creatures?
